# Zend_Http_Adapter & error message

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am currently using zend framework for my project, this is my problem.

I have a form which is not created by Zend Form but just manual HTML form. I have one  element with it. Now my problem is that I want to set a custom error message for the errors that will be catched by the Zend_Http_Adapter for the invalid files being uploaded.

I do not want to end up like this:
    FILE 'sample.doc' HAS A FALSE EXTENSION 
or things alike.

Is there any way to set custom error message for that?

Thanks in advance.. :D

Comment: Have you tried using standard PHP TRY/CATCH exception handling? Add in the Zend Flash Messanger and catch the appropriate errors, write a message regarding the error and redirect them to a page to display said message (it could be or often is the same page as the form).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, here is how you can translate the default message:

```
$adapter->addValidator('Extension', false,
                       array(
                           'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif',
                           'case' => false,
                           'messages' => array(
                               // override false extension message
                               Zend_Validate_File_Extension::FALSE_EXTENSION =>
                              'I do not accept files of that extension'
                           )
));
```

You can generally override any `Zend_Validate` error message by passing an array of `messages` to the validator where the key is the specific error from the validator, and the value is the translated message.